# Perl, Telegram, WWW::Telegram::BotAPI how send array of array?

Tags: json, perl, telegram, telegram-bot

I use WWW::Telegram::BotAPI (Perl implementation of the Telegram Bot API) for simple bot development.

I need create a custom keyboard (https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) for reply (sendMessage method).

Telegram API for keyboards https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#replykeyboardmarkup describe field 'keyboard' with type Array of Array of string.

Example:

```
my @buttons=(['one','two'],['three','four'],['five']);
```

But i make something wrong

```
print Dumper $api->SendMessage
                    ({
                    chat_id => $from_id,
                    text    => 'question text ?',
                    reply_to_message_id => $message_id,
                    reply_markup => {
                                    keyboard =>  (['one','two'],['three','four'],['five']);
                                    resize_keyboard => 1,
                                    one_time_keyboard => 1
                                    }
                    });
```

in output dump - reply_markup not present. What wrong can do? How to define 'keyboard' field correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In a hash, all the values must be scalars. You can't use a list as the value of `keyboard`. I'd try an anonymous array instead:

```
{ keyboard => [ [ 'one', 'two' ], [ 'three', 'four' ], [ 'five' ] ],
  resize_keyboard => ...
```

Also note that semicolon is a statement terminator, you can't use it instead of a comma.

Comment: It's an anonymous array reference, not an anonymous array.

Comment: @simbabque: OK, but as anonymous array isn't possible without a reference, I used the shorter term.

Comment: That is kind of true as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#libs
use JSON;

#telegram Reply Menus

my $telegramEndPoint = "https://ip+token/sendMessage";
my $textMessage = "My Keyboard";
my $chat_id = 12345;

#create a hash of your reply markup
my %replyMarkup  = (
        keyboard    => [[ "One", "Two" ]]
        );#your keyboard must be an array of array

#Json Encode them
my $buttons = encode_json \%replyMarkup;
sendTelegram($telegramEndPoint,$textMessage,$chat_id,$replyMarkup)

sub sendTelegramMenus{
    #usage
    #sendTelegram($telegramEndPoint,$textMessage,$chat_id,$replyMarkup)
    my(@values) = @_;
    my $telegramEndPoint = $values[0];
    my $textMessage = $values[1];
    my $chat_id = $values[2];
    my $replyMarkup = $values[3];

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
    my $completeUrl =  $telegramEndPoint.'chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.$textMessage.'&reply_markup='.$replyMarkup;
    print "URL: ".$completeUrl."\n\n";
    my $response = $ua->get($completeUrl);
    my $content  = $response->decoded_content();
    my $resCode = $response->code();


    print "RESPONSE CODE $resCode \n Content: $content\n\n";
}
```

#That should Work